# Работа с UART в ESP2688 через Arduino IDE

Tags: http, wifi, веб-сервер, arduino, uart

Постоянно выдаёт "0", если не запитать UART - "255", и ему всё ровно, что бы не посылалось по UART'у.

```
s = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>Sireal = "+String(Serial.read())+"</html>\r\n\r\n";
```

Написано на [Arduino IDE for ESP](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases)

Comment: Параметры передачи: скорость, четность, число бит (включая стоповые) проверены? Осциллограф показывает на ноге Tx что передача данных по 232-му реально идет?

Comment: Осциллограф показывает передача данных идет в обе стороны, но ESP не читает данные.

Comment: Тогда параметры передачи